# How to fix VideoError (ExoPlaybackException: Source error) in Flutter video player?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, exoplayer, video-player

I'm building a Flutter video player app and encountering the following error when trying to play videos:

```
[ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: 
PlatformException(VideoError, Video player had error 
com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlaybackException: 
Source error, null, null)
```

**Code (Minimal Reproducible Example):**

```dart
    class VideoInfo extends StatefulWidget {
      // ... other code ... 
    
    class _VideoInfoState extends State<VideoInfo> {
   
      late VideoPlayerController _controller;
     
      
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
            body: 
    // ... other code ... 

      Widget _playView(BuildContext context){
        final controller =_controller;
        if(controller!=null&&controller.value.isInitialized){
          return Container(
            height: 300,
            width: 300,
            child: VideoPlayer(controller),
          );
        }else{
          return Text("Being initialized pls wait");
        }
      }
      _onTapVideo(int index){
        final controller = VideoPlayerController.network(videoInfo[index]["videoUrl"]);
        _controller= controller;
        setState(() {
        });
```

**What I've tried:**

- Checked video URL validity.
- Ensured the `video_player` dependency is included.
- Added `android.permission.INTERNET` to the Android manifest.

Comment: Have you got the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are assigning a value of the same variable.

Use,

```
_controller = controller;
```

instead of,

```
_controller=_controller;
```

Comment: Hello Dhaval Asodariya, I replace that line of code, but not luck, It trows me this error: [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)]

Answer (score 1):

When you use late, this means that the variable can be initialized with a delay, so you need to initialize it before you can use it. You can break the debug at the _onTapVideo function to see if your _controller=_controller， is really initialized ？

Comment: Hello lifeee, in what exactly line of code I have to replace it?